# How to talk about my new habit?

Tags: grammar, past-habitual

I started playing football daily last month. 
How to describe that now? 
Can I say (I have started playing football daily recently)

Comment: I believe you could say: I've been playing football daily for a month.

Comment: *I recently started playing football daily.*

Answer (score 1):

You could simply say

> I **have been** playing football daily since last month.

Using the *present perfect* to signal something began in the past and continues.

You could also say:

> I started playing football regularly since last month.